# iOS OpenGL ES2 make change in vertex buffer object

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I have a terrain in OpenGL. I want to dynamicly change the space between points.
But when the vertex data is send to the vertex buffer object, i cannot modify anything.
The only thing i can do is delete the VBO and create a replacement VBO with new positions of each point.
Is there a best way to do this ?

Comment: You can use `glBufferSubData()` to modify data in a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it sounds like you want `glBufferSubData`.

If you planned to modify the data often, first setup your VBO's initial state:

```
float[] positions = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int numberOfPositions = 6;
int vbo = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * numberOfPositions, positions, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Then later say you want to change the last two values to `1`, you would do this:

```
float[] update = { 1, 1 };
int offset = 4
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * offset, update);
```

Check out the [docs.gl page on glBufferSubData](http://docs.gl/gl4/glBufferSubData) for more information.